# Prolog - longest sublist within a list

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, longest-path

I am trying to get the longest sublist within a list. I need a rule that recursively searches a list of lists and determines which list has the longest length.

For example:
input: `[[1],[1,2],[],[1,2,3,4],[5,6]]`
output: `[1,2,3,4]`

This is what I have so far:

```
max([H|T], Path, Length) :-
  length(H, L),
  (L @> Length -> 
  max(T, H, L) ;
  max(T, Path, Length) ).
```

I would like `max()` to work like this:

```
? max([[1],[1,2],[],[1,2,3,4],[5,6]], Path, Distance).
Path = [1,2,3,4]
Distance = 4
```

When I run a trace, this is the output:

```
{trace}
| ?- max([[1],[1,2],[],[1,2,3,4],[5,6]], Path, Distance).
      1    1  Call: max([[1],[1,2],[],[1,2,3,4],[5,6]],_307,_308) ? 
      2    2  Call: length([1],_387) ? 
      2    2  Exit: length([1],1) ? 
      3    2  Call: 1@>_308 ? 
      3    2  Exit: 1@>_308 ? 
      4    2  Call: max([[1,2],[],[1,2,3,4],[5,6]],[1],1) ? 
      5    3  Call: length([1,2],_462) ? 
      5    3  Exit: length([1,2],2) ? 
      6    3  Call: 2@>1 ? 
      6    3  Exit: 2@>1 ? 
      7    3  Call: max([[],[1,2,3,4],[5,6]],[1,2],2) ? 
      8    4  Call: length([],_537) ? 
      8    4  Exit: length([],0) ? 
      9    4  Call: 0@>2 ? 
      9    4  Fail: 0@>2 ? 
      9    4  Call: max([[1,2,3,4],[5,6]],[1,2],2) ? 
     10    5  Call: length([1,2,3,4],_587) ? 
     10    5  Exit: length([1,2,3,4],4) ? 
     11    5  Call: 4@>2 ? 
     11    5  Exit: 4@>2 ? 
     12    5  Call: max([[5,6]],[1,2,3,4],4) ? 
     13    6  Call: length([5,6],_662) ? 
     13    6  Exit: length([5,6],2) ? 
     14    6  Call: 2@>4 ? 
     14    6  Fail: 2@>4 ? 
     14    6  Call: max([],[1,2,3,4],4) ? 
     14    6  Fail: max([],[1,2,3,4],4) ? 
     12    5  Fail: max([[5,6]],[1,2,3,4],4) ? 
      9    4  Fail: max([[1,2,3,4],[5,6]],[1,2],2) ? 
      7    3  Fail: max([[],[1,2,3,4],[5,6]],[1,2],2) ? 
      4    2  Fail: max([[1,2],[],[1,2,3,4],[5,6]],[1],1) ? 
      1    1  Fail: max([[1],[1,2],[],[1,2,3,4],[5,6]],_307,_308) ? 

(2 ms) no
```

I believe the issue is that I am not handling the occurrence of an empty set "`[]`". However, I have attempted several different methods and am unable to get my desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define loop ending clause and need one more parameter for returning.

```
max([], _, Length, Length).
max([H|T], Path, Length, RetLength) :-
  length(H, L),
  ( L @> Length -> 
    max(T, H, L,RetLength) ;
    max(T, Path, Length,RetLength) 
  ).
```

Test:

```
?- max([[1],[1,2],[],[1,2,3,4],[5,6]], Path, Distance,Len).
Len = 4.
```